# Passing for loop results to VAR fails

Tags: bash

I am counting the number of files contained in a directory where ZIPs are dropped

When I run this to `echo $VAR` later on to an email

```
 VAR=`for i in `find . -mtime 0 -name '*XML*' -exec ls '{}' \;`; do unzip -l "$i"| awk -F. '{if ($2=="XML") print $0}'|wc -l; done| paste -sd+ | bc`
```

it fails with this error:

```
-bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
-bash: command substitution: line 1: `; do unzip -l "$i"| awk -F. '{if ($2=="XML") print $0}'|wc -l; done| paste -sd+ | bc'
-bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
-bash: .: -m: invalid option
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
```

By itself, the `for` loop runs fine.

It seems that I am missing something re: escaping quotes. Any idea?

Comment: You need to escape the inner backticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to nest back-quotes, you must escape it:

```
VAR=`for i in \`find . -mtime 0 -name '*XML*' -exec ls '{}' \;\`; do unzip -l "$i"| awk -F. '{if ($2=="XML") print $0}'|wc -l; done| paste -sd+ | bc`
```

But, as *choroba* suggested, it is probably better to use `$(...)`:

```
VAR=$(for i in $(find . -mtime 0 -name '*XML*' -exec ls '{}' \;); do unzip -l "$i"| awk -F. '{if ($2=="XML") print $0}'|wc -l; done| paste -sd+ | bc)
```

Especially because if you decide to use back-quotes inside double quotes, you must be careful with escaping internal double-quotes:

```
test="example `echo \"internal\"`"
```

When with parenthesis it becomes "cleaner":

```
test="example $(echo "internal")"
```

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 4):

Backquotes cannot be nested. Use `$( ... )` instead.